# There exists a TM $M$ such that both $L(M)$ and $L\left(M_{\star}\right)$ are NP-Hard

Tags: computational-complexity

I need to prove the following :

Assume the $P\ne NP$

There exists a TM $M$ such that both $L(M)$ and $L\left(M_{\star}\right)$ are NP-Hard. let $L\left(M_{\star}\right)$ be the TM obtained from $M$ by swapping the accept and reject states.

Comment: You don’t need $P \ne NP$ for this. Are you familiar with the time hierarchy theorem?

Comment: I know that Atm is NP -HARD so I thought to make a polinomial reduction from Atm to M and Mstar  but I can't come up with a M